# Text/XML Email being received with XML Email Body Converted to Attachment

Tags: php, xml, email, email-attachments, sendgrid

I have a server(A) that sends plain text emails using PHP mail to multiple servers (Y,Z) with identical setups/versions.  The emails in question contain XML in its body, so when the emails arrives on the corresponding servers, the XML in the email body is parsed and processed.

- Server Y has SendGrid set up, so SendGrid is receiving the emails from server A then forwarding it to server Y.
- Server Z does not have SendGrid, but just uses the built in Unix emails.

Ultimately, all incoming emails on both servers Y and Z run through the same functions to parse emails.

When I have server A send a content-type: text/xml email to server Z, it arrives fine, and server Z has no problem parsing the XML out of the email body.

However, when I have server A send the exact same email to server Y, it arrives with the XML in an attachment, and the email body is empty.

I've asked SendGrid support to see if maybe they are doing something that would cause the email body to be converted to an attachment, but they insist they don't do anything to incoming emails.

I'm pretty stumped, so I'm coming here to see if anyone know any clues as to what may be causing this issue.